# Caps Lock switches on when I press Enter Key

Tags: laptop, keyboard, toshiba-laptop

I am using a brand new Toshiba Satellite C850 i5212 model for last 20 days. From last 3 days, I am facing a problem with my laptop keyboard. When I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, it is functioning as <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is not working.

Still I don't know if there are other keys malfunctioning. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that your Laptop is brand new and you still not used much so its batter to contact Toshiba Service Center rather than posting here and asking for the solution you will find different different solution but may be its hardware problem please take help of experts in Toshiba care.

Comment: Thanks. i posted here because it could be a minor problem that i can fix.. I did Windows Update recently and i thought that could have caused the trouble with my laptop keyword function keys... Okay, i go for Toshiba care.. Thanks again James